# (Auto) Flipped Faces

Tags: mesh

Update, mad I had to click each individual item by hand, if anyone finds a way to auto do this process, please answer here"

Is there a way to auto select only the red faces that are pointing towards user? so I can flip all normals at once? instead of clicking on each object and selecting flip normals.

Cheers!

[image]

Comment: Do all the red pieces have the same orientation? If so, you could select one of them and then pick _Select > Select Similar > Normal_ from the top left menu.

Comment: (can't) They are duplicates of the others around, I'm unsure how they are even flipped. I would manually do it but they're 4 windows :S I will do it if no answer. I might look at chat GTP and see if it's possible.

Comment: Why wouldn't select similar work in this case? Also you can try recalculate if you haven't already.

Answer (score 1):

[Christopher Bennett](https://blender.stackexchange.com/users/75504/christopher-bennett) is absolutely right.

1. Find a face, that is exactly parallel to camera sensor (perpendicular to camera view, the one you're looking at **exactly** "face-on"). If there isn't one, or you're unsure, you could create a temporary camera (assuming you don't want to mess with existing one), set its rotations to $<0, 0, 0>$ (pointing down), create a plane, <kbd>✲ Ctrl</kbd><kbd>P</kbd> parent it to the camera, then set this new camera as scene camera and <kbd>✲ Ctrl</kbd><kbd>⎇ Alt</kbd><kbd>Numpad 0</kbd> align the camera to view:

[image]

2. If the face you found is a separate object (like with the camera trick), just select it together with the main object(s), then <kbd>⭾ Tab</kbd> go to edit mode. (You may want to scale this face down and move it out of the way if you followed the camera trick.)
3. If the chosen face appears blue (normal pointing towards you correctly; it does if you followed the camera trick), just select it and <kbd>⎇ Alt</kbd><kbd>N</kbd>, <kbd>F</kbd> flip it.
4. With the chosen face still selected, <kbd>⬆ Shift</kbd><kbd>G</kbd>, <kbd>N</kbd> Select by similar normal, and in the popup panel (if you don't see it, press <kbd>F9</kbd>) type `0.5`. This will select all faces looking more towards you than away from you. Now with faces selected just <kbd>⎇ Alt</kbd><kbd>N</kbd>, <kbd>F</kbd> flip the normals:

[image]

**Though beware, this will flip the backfaces as well! In your case you may want to first hide faces you don't want to affect by e.g. <kbd>L</kbd> selecting entire hulls of other geometry and <kbd>H</kbd> hiding them. Or after applying the method, <kbd>A</kbd> select all, <kbd>⬆ Shift</kbd><kbd>N</kbd> Recalculate Outside.**

Answer (score 0):

> #### [image: AI Icon] Warning, Potential AI generated content⚠️
>
> **This post is suspected to have been generated with the help of an artificial intelligence, chat bot, or other language model tools without proper attribution.**
>
> There is reason to believe this post was not written by a human due to its structure, and grammatical construction, and has been marked by our community.
> Current AI chat bots are a language models, that means they are like a parrot, they can mimic human language well, but they are built to write **seemingly** logical, **seemingly** factual grammatically valid text, rather than actually **be correct**, like a human would.
> The veracity of the following content cannot be ascertained.
> See the [Concerns regarding AI generated content](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/384396).

Chat GTP:

Unfortunately, as of my knowledge cutoff in September 2021, Blender's Python API doesn't provide direct access to the face orientation information displayed in the viewport. Therefore, it is not possible to automate the flipping of the red faces based on the face orientation overlay using a script.

To flip faces based on their orientation, you would need to rely on alternative methods or tools within Blender. One option is to manually select the red faces in Edit Mode using the face orientation overlay, then use the "Flip Normals" command (Ctrl+N) to flip their orientations.